# Como finalizar minha aplicação WPF e inicializar ela novamente?

Tags: c#, wpf

Eu tenho em minha aplicação uma tela de configuração de banco de dados, na qual uma vez configurada eu tenho que fechar o sistema e depois abrir novamente para surtir efeito as alterações realizadas. Como eu posso fazer isso de uma maneira automática?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora usando WPF, desde que você possa adicionar uma referência ao assembly `System.Windows.Form` (não vejo motivo para não poder), você pode usar um método do namespace `System.Windows.Forms`:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
```

Veja: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart(v=vs.110).aspx